# maven-bundle-plugin Creates unexpected Import-Package content

Tags: java, maven, osgi, apache-felix, maven-bundle-plugin

I build all my bundles using `maven-bundle-plugin` and after some tests with `pax:provision` I found that it is creating a `Import-Package=org.osgi.framework;version="[1.8,0)"` on all bundles and at the moment of installing the bundles in Felix then I get all my bundles unresolved because of `org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.domain.mybundle [55]: Unable to resolve 55.0: missing requirement
[55.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.8.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))`.

Why is `maven-bundle-plugin` creating this header if I have no direct dependency to that package. I also tried to add the dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.apache.felix.framework</artifactId>
  <version>4.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And it still uses the version `1.8.0`. Any idea why?

**UPDATE**

Checking again, the bundles do use the `org.osgi.framework` in the Activator. but this class `org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator` comes from the bundle:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
  <version>4.3.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

So again, why isn't the `maven-bundle-plugin` using the version `4.3.1` instead of `1.8.0`? And in other bundles it uses version `1.6.2`.

**UPDATE 20-3-2015**

This is the exception I receive after executing `mvn pax:provision`

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.classdomain.per
sistence [47]: Unable to resolve 47.0: missing requirement[47.0] osgi.wiring.package; 
(&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.8.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))ERROR: 
Bundle org.classdomain.persistence [47] Error starting file:bundles/org.classdomain.per
sistence_0.1.0.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle
 org.classdomain.persistence [47]: Unable to resolve 47.0: missing requirement [47.0] o
sgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.8.0)(!(versio
n>=2.0.0))))

        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:4002)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2045)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1299)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Definitely, seems like this exception only happens when using `mvn pax:provision`, if I install the same bundles in a stand alone Felix instance then every thing works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Import-Package statements are built according to the defined package versions in the libraries you use. In your case you have a dependency to org.apache.felix.framework which defines these exports (e.g. org.osgi.framework version 1.8) in its Manifest.

If you only have a depenency to org.osgi.core 4.3.1 then the package org.osgi.framework should be defined with version 1.6. So this should work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, but if I use dependency org.osgi.core 4.3.1 then the package defines an Import-Package to org.osgi.framework 1.6, then it (Felix) says there is no org.osgi.framework 1.6! so what is the point for the maven-bundle-plugin in changing it to 1.6 if it will appear as 'missing requirement'?

Comment: Looks like something is wrong in your setup. I always use org.osgi.core 4.3.1 and the resulting bundle works on all osgi frameworks I worked with (felix, equinox). The import range of [1.6,0) means that any version >=1.6 of this package is ok. So if felix 4.6.0 offers the 1.8 version it will be compatible. Can you post the exact error you get when using the org.osgi.core 4.3.1 spec?

Comment: Hi, just updated the question and posted detailed error received by Felix under `pax:provision`. I finally tested it without the Pax plugin and it works. So, I ended up by removing the Pax plugin and copying the generated bundles along with dependencies to another folder to then install them all manually to a Felix instance (bundle folder) and test the bundles from there.